# Take values from another spreadsheet, based on a value on the original workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking automatically to calculate the average of 40 values that come from a .csv file, which I have managed to do.

My problem is I would like it to take the values from any separate workbook based on the cell value from the original workbook, so this can automatically calculate the average from any one of a number of available spreadsheets.

This is the formula I'm using currently:

```
=Sample1.csv!C1
```

And this is the what I tried, which obviously doesn't work:

```
=B4.csv!C1
```

With B4 containing the word `Sample1` or any other Sample Number.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you can use to refer to a cell on another sheet

```
=INDIRECT(B1 & "!C1")
```

Where B1 has the sheet name and you get the value of cell C1 from it.

It can be used to get data from another workbook , so long as the other workbook is open.

eg 
    =INDIRECT("[Book1.xlsx]a.csv!$A$1")

```
=INDIRECT("[" & B1 & "]!$A$1")
```

Where B1 has the name of the workbook

In practise you might use:

```
=INDIRECT(B1 & "!" & C1)
```

Where C1 contains (ie stores as a value!) the address of the cell you want to reference.  Thsi is useful as it allows you to copy the formulas such that the addresses change.

It is better to use the CELL function as follows which uses CELL to get the Address of A1 as text eg "$A$1".  This means the formula can easily be copied and pasted into the cells you want it to be in.

```
=INDIRECT(B1 & "!" & CELL("address",A1)
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Will that work for the data being on a completely separate spreadsheet?

Comment: Again sorry to confuse you, but I would like the data to come from any number of different workbooks based on the value of B4 of the original workbook?

Comment: Using that formula, it returns a #REF error, where the cell C1 is highlighted on the original workbook instead of on the data workbook

Comment: "that formula" meaning which one?   Were all workbook open?  "where C1 is hightlighted" meaning?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Indirect() function to have Excel interpret a text string as a cell reference, and this string can be constructed with the text values from one (or more) cells.
So in your example use:
    =INDIRECT(B4 & "!C1")
which retrieves the value "Sample1" from B4 and concatenates this with the second part of the string to give "Sample1!C1" that Indirect() then uses as an address & retrieves the value from there.

Comment: Thats great, will that work for the data being on a completely separate spreadsheet not a separate sheet of the same workbook?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the workbook filename to make the full address. e.g.    
    =INDIRECT("[Book1.xlsx]" & B4 & "!C1")
or of course that could be another cell reference rather than hardcode the workbook name.

If you're getting #REF errors meaning there's a problem with the address, a quick check is to remove the INDIRECT so that the cell shows the address you've constructed instead of using it for the lookup. Compare that to what you'd get by just typing a = then clicking on the cell in the other workbook.

Comment: Again sorry to confuse you, but I would like the data to come from any number of different workbooks based on the value of B4 of the original workbook?

Comment: You just need to decide the best way to include the workbook name and sheet name in your 'main' workbook that's doing the average calculation and lookup.  
 
Simplest way if you have one worksheet per workbook would be put the workbook name into cell B4 so it reads `[Book1.xlsx]Sample1`  
 
Or if you have several worksheets in each workbook you could put a list of all these into your main workbook and use a Vlookup function to get the workbook filename associated with each worksheet name.

Comment: Okay thank you, I think that's the answer I was looking for